# align images horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I align images contained in a div horizontally? That is with a fixed width.

Example code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="random">
<a href=""><img src=".jpg" /><span></span></a>
<a href=".html"><h2>Title</h2></a><p>Info</p><p>Dd/Mm/Yyyy</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#random{ 
max-width: 650px
}
```

Comment: You only have 1 image here and some invalid HTML (`a` cannot contain block level elements like `h2` or `p`).  Are you trying to align the image to the `h2` or to another image formatted the same way?

Comment: In HTML5 it is perfectly valid for links to wrap around block level elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually floats can do the trick to align elements horizontally quite nicely. Use that inconjunction with clearfix class on the containing (parent) element so the floats don't break your other page layout.

## HTML

```
<div class="horiz clearfix">
    <div><a href="www.google.com"><img src="https://www.pathe.nl/themes/main_theme/gfx/icons/placeholder-large.png"/>
        </a></div>
    <div><a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><h2>Title</h2></a><p>Info</p><p>Dd/Mm/Yyyy</p></div>
</div>
<div class="horiz clearfix">
    <div><a href="www.google.com"><img src="https://www.pathe.nl/themes/main_theme/gfx/icons/placeholder-large.png"/>
        </a></div>
    <div><a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><h2>Title</h2></a><p>Info</p><p>Dd/Mm/Yyyy</p></div>
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.horiz > * {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}​
```

Comment: Note that the clearfix was copied from [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: And HTML5 Boilerplate copied it from Nicolas Gallagher (see: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  background:#d5d5d5;
  }
.container img{
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200X200/000/fff"/>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain why that would be a solution, or at least add some explanation to what you've posted

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="random">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#random{ 
    max-width: 650px
}

#random img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
}
```